# Start vino-server automatically at startup

Tags: startup, vnc, bodhi

I am using Bodhi Linux, and `vino-server` in it.
I can connect neatly from Win 10, following the same procedure [I am used to do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213657/vino-server-not-starting-after-reboot) to connect to Ubuntu boxes.

Now I want `vino-server` to start automatically on boot.
What I use in Ubuntu (1. Add `vino-server` to startup applications, 2. Have Gnome automatically logging into my user ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012447/226614))) didn't work for me here.
The reason: I could not find a way to startup an arbitrary application in Bodhi Linux. I found how to add startup applications only from a given list, and `vino-server` is not in there ([source](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/start-applications-automatically-linux-boots/): "There doesn't appear to be a way to add custom commands or scripts in the tool so if the utility or application is not found automatically it may require further research to add it").

Other alternatives repeatedly found (which I never tried in Ubuntu) did not work for me here:

1. Setting up a `~/.config/autostart/vino_server.desktop` file ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1267038/226614)).
2. Starting `vino-server` as a service ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1010860/226614)).

The contents of my `~/.config/autostart/vino_server.desktop` is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
Name=vino Server
```

How can I make this work?

(perhaps finding a way to add an arbitrary application at startup, method #1 above).

**Note**:
In my case, I don't have `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` set (I do have many other `$XDG_...` variables).
I don't know the reason for this, and whether this may cause `vino_server.desktop` not being run on login, method #1.

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107829/226614), "a compliant desktop environment (for the freedesktop.org / XDG Base Directory Specification) will search `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart` for any `.desktop` files and execute them on startup. So a missing `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` might be a problem.

OTOH, [official documentation](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables) states that "`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user-specific configuration files should be stored. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.config` should be used."
I don't know if the latter means one should expect `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to be always set, unless Moksha (the desktop environment) were not XDG-compliant.

**Related**:

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/178567/how-to-add-a-program-as-a-startup-application-from-a-terminal
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/598195/how-to-add-a-script-to-startup-applications-from-the-command-line
3. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en
4. https://vitux.com/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-ubuntu/
5. https://www.shells.com/l/en-US/tutorial/How-to-Manage-Startup-Programs-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://myridia.com/dev_posts/view/2222) showed me how to add applications to start with login.

I added `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` to `.e/e/applications/startup/startupcommands`, logged out, logged in, and I had `vino-server` running.
One of the few points where I found Bodhi differs from Ubuntu, so far.